# Absolute and conditional convergence of integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I have the following improper integral:
$$
\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right)dx
$$
And I need to figure out, whether this integral converges absolutely, conditionally or diverges.

I think that it converges conditionally. To show this I did this:

$$
\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right) = 
-2\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\sin(x) + \cos(x)}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)\right)
$$

Then I used the used the fact that $\sin(x) \sim x, \text{when } x \to 0$, so the following integral is "equivalent":

$$
-2\int \limits_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)}{2x}dx = 
-\int \limits_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{2x}dx
$$

Now I believe it is possible to show that this integral converges (maybe using [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)), and we can do same things for integral with module, and then somehow show divergence of it (or maybe convergence).

Could you tell me if I'm doing it correct, or could you give me some hints on how to solve this.

Comment: You're doing great so far (except for a sign error and a lost factor $2$ at the end). Note that since $\lvert \varphi - \sin \varphi\rvert \leqslant \lvert \varphi\rvert^3$, the difference between the exact integral and your approximation is absolutely integrable. Hence the integral is absolutely/conditionally convergent if and only if the last integral is.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Is it always true that after changing some functions to equivalent ones, the resulting integral will converge absolutely/conditionally if and only if the original is. Or it is true only in this special case?

Comment: That depends on what "equivalent" means. If you look at asymptotic equivalence, so there is a function $\varepsilon$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \varepsilon(x) = 0$, and $f$ and $g$ satisfy the relation $f(x) = \bigl(1 + \varepsilon(x)\bigr)\cdot g(x)$, then it can be that one of $\int f$ and $\int g$ converges conditionally, but the other doesn't. But if you look at the difference of the functions, and $\int \lvert f-g\rvert$ converges absolutely, then the convergence behaviour of $\int f$ and $\int g$ is the same. One converges conditionally/absolutely if and only if the other does.

Comment: And here, when looking at $\sin (\alpha(x))\cdot\sin(\beta(x))$ with the specific $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given, $\int_1^{\infty} \lvert \alpha(x)\beta(x) - \sin(\alpha(x))\sin(\beta(x))\rvert\,dx < +\infty$.